# failing to Deploy from GIT Repository within Cpanel into LIVE /public_html

Tags: git, cpanel

Some help guys,

I have setup GIT Repository in Cpanel (/home/repositories/mysite) and pushed all the content into from my localhost successfully.

However my challenge is - Nor Manual or Automatic deployment is NOT working from the repository into public_html (live website). It keeps showing as if it is updating but nothing is happening.

The post-receive succesfully updates and below is my .cpanel.yml file config.

````
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/
    - /bin/cp -R app $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp -R assets $DEPLOYPATH
    exclude:
    - .env
    - app/Config/Email.php```


I have deleted and recreated the repository and also tried to add it onto my localhost. All is fine but the final stage is the problem.

NOTE: my localhost pushes on both github and cpanel and branch for cpanel is "main"
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here are a couple things to check:

- Make sure you're replacing *user* in "/home/user/public_html/" with the actual username in the directory path. In my case: home/ameridg3/public_html.
- Through the cPanel file manager, navigate to .cpanel > logs. (you will need to "show hidden files" to see it - the settings button for that is in the top right corner) In the logs folder you should find the git_deploy.log for each deploy you've attempted. That should help you understand what error is going on.